# Matplotlib: data is mysteriously offset

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a series of time segments as by x data, and y data is just static (y=1)

However, my code is subtracting 0.5 from the x data, and I don't know why. Reproducible code below:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
a = [[0,2,0],
     [2,6,1],
     [6,12,0],
     [12,13,1]]
a=np.array(a)
a_segs =[[i[0],i[1]] for i in a]
y1=[[1,1] for i in a]
clr= {0:'red',1:'blue'}
a_clr=[]
for i in a:
    if i[2] in clr:
        a_clr.append(clr[i[2]])
for i,j,z in zip(a_segs,y1,a_clr):
    plt.plot(i,j,color=z,linewidth=20)
plt.axvline(x=5.5,linestyle="--")
plt.axvline(x=1.5,linestyle='--')
plt.ylim(0,1)
plt.xlim(0,15)
plt.yticks([0,1,2,3])
plt.show()
```

I've placed the dashed line to indicate the second element of my data (2,6) that has been changed to (1.5,5.5)

[image: resulting graph]

Comment: It's caused by `linewidth=20`. You should probably plot `matplotlib.patches.Rectangle` if you want rectangles.

Comment: The endcap of each line segment has a width, which overlaps the previous segment, which you can see if you use `y1 = [[1, 1], [2, 2], [1, 1], [2, 2]]`. See [plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LMopB.png)

Answer (score 1):

Here you go! explanation is included too.

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
a = [[0,2,0],
     [2,6,1],
     [6,12,0],
     [12,13,1]]
a=np.array(a)
a_segs =[[i[0],i[1]] for i in a]
y1=[[1,1] for i in a]
clr= {0:'red',1:'blue'}
a_clr=[]
for i in a:
    if i[2] in clr:
        print (i[2])
        a_clr.append(clr[i[2]])
for i,j,z in zip(a_segs,y1,a_clr):
    plt.plot(i,j,color=z,linewidth=20, solid_capstyle='butt')#as you increase the linewidth size the data will be shifted slightly, so to fix this you need to specify solid_capstyle='butt' in the plot() function. 
plt.axvline(x=6,linestyle="--") #updated
plt.axvline(x=2,linestyle='--') #updated
#plt.ylim(0,1) #no need this
plt.xlim(0,15)
plt.yticks([0,1,2,3])
plt.show()
```

[image]